# JavaScript keyCode - which key was clicked, using foreign keyboard layouts

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Could not find a solution to what seems to me as a simple problem.

I'm using `var a = evt.keyCode;` to determine which key was clicked.

The problem is that the value I get is the ASCII code of the clicked key and not the real character that was clicked.

If, for example, a user is using a French keyboard, clicking the <kbd>7</kbd> key is <kbd>é</kbd>,
so instead of getting the ASCII code of <kbd>é</kbd>, I get 55 which is the ASCII code of <kbd>7</kbd>.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using the `onkeypress` or `onkeydown` event?  You should be using the former, `onkeypress`, to ascertain the correct character code for the key that was pressed.  In the event handler, check the `event.which` and `event.keyCode` properties:

```
function whichKey(evt) {
    alert(String.fromCharCode(evt.which || evt.keyCode));
}
```

**Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7LsMk/**

Comment: Ok, I see your point here. I'm using onkeydown since this is not my js code (taken from http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/jsactb.aspx). 
I will try to modify the code so it would work with onkeypress.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`var unicode=evt.charCode? evt.charCode : evt.keyCode;
var actualkey=String.fromCharCode(unicode);`